# Перенос данных между таблицами и их сохранение

Tags: база-данных, yii2

Работаю с фреймворком YII2 совсем недавно и по этому много чего еще не знаю и не понимаю. В БД есть 3 таблицы)

Таблица хранящая *название тем* **S_QUIZ_TOPIC** с полями:

```
integer $ID_REC
string $NAME_TOPIC
integer $RANDOM
integer $MAX_TIME
string $DT_UP
integer $STATUS
```

Таблица хранящая *вопросы* **S_QUIZ_QUESTION** с полями:

```
integer $ID_REC
string $NAME_QUEST
string $TEXT_QUEST
string $MSG_QUEST
integer $RANDOM
string $DT_UP
integer $STATUS
```

И связывающая эти 2 таблицы **S_QUIZ_TQ**:

```
integer $ID_REC
integer $ID_TOPIC
integer $ID_QUESTION
string $DT_UP
integer $STATUS
```

**Задача следующая:**

Нужно реализовать 2 таблицы, в одной должен выводится список всех вопросов (Поле $NAME_QUEST), которые есть в таблице **S_QUIZ_QUESTION**, во второй должен выводиться список вопросов, которые входят в эту тему. Реализовать перенос данных между этими таблицами и сохранение их в бд в связывающую таблицу.

Сделал 2 таблицы в которых отображаются следующие данные:

1) В левой таблице выводится список всех вопросов из таблицы **S_QUIZ_QUESTION**.

2) В правой таблице выводится список вопросов, которые входят в данную тему.

Вывел данные в таблицу следующим образом:

```
<!-- Навигация -->
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified panel panel-primary" role="tablist">
      <li class="active">
         <a href="#questionintopik" aria-controls="questionintopik" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Вопросы входящие в эту тему</a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="#questioninexam" aria-controls="questioninexam" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Вопросы входящие в экзамен</a>
      </li>
   </ul>

   <div class="tab-content">
   <!--Вопросы входящие в эту тему-->
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active panel panel-primary" id="questionintopik">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
            <!-- Левая таблица -->
               <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
                  <h4>Вопросы не входящие в эту тему</h4>
                  <input id="search-avaliable">
                  <a href="#" id="btn-refresh"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> </a> <br>
                  <?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'ID_REC', $LeftItems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%']) ?>
               <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
            </div>
         <div class="col-lg-1">
            <!-- Кнопки -->
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <a href="#" id="btn-add" class="btn btn-success">&gt;&gt;</a><br>
            <a href="#" id="btn-remove" class="btn btn-danger">&lt;&lt;</a>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-5">
            <!-- Правая таблица -->
            <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
               <h4>Вопросы входящие в эту тему</h4>
               <input id="search-assigned"><br>
               <?= Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'ID_REC', $RightItems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%']) ?>
            <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Теперь возник вопрос, как мне реализовать перенос данных между этими таблицами? Я могу выбрать любую тему щелчком мыши в левой таблице. Но что мне теперь следует сделать, что бы при нажатии на соответствующие клавиши выбранный вопрос переносился из левой таблицы в правую и сохранялся в бд и наоборот?

**Код контроллера:**

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $searchModel = new SQuizQuestionSearch();
    $dataProviderLeft = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProviderRight = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $model->getQuestions(),
    ]);

    $LeftItems = ArrayHelper::map($dataProviderLeft->getModels(),'ID_REC','NAME_QUEST');
    $RightItems = ArrayHelper::map($dataProviderRight->getModels(), 'ID_REC', 'NAME_QUEST');

    return $this->render('view', [

        'model' => $model,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,

        'dataProviderLeft' => $dataProviderLeft,
        'LeftItems' => $LeftItems,

        'dataProviderRight' => $dataProviderRight,
        'RightItems' => $RightItems,
    ]);
}
```

**Код модели S_QUIZ_TOPIC:**

```
public function getSQUIZTQs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SQUIZTQ::className(), ['ID_TOPIC' => 'ID_REC']);
}

public function getQuestions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SQuizQuestion::className(), ['ID_REC' => 'ID_QUESTION'])->via('sQUIZTQs');
}
```

**Код модели S_QUIZ_QUESTION:**

```
public function getSQUIZTQs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SQUIZTQ::className(), ['ID_QUESTION' => 'ID_REC']);
}

public function getTopic()
{
    return $this->hasMany(SQuizTopic::className(), ['ID_REC' => 'ID_TOPIC'])->via('sQUIZTQs');
}
```

**Код модели S_QUIZ_TQ:**

```
public function getIDQUESTION()
{
    return $this->hasOne(SQuizQuestion::className(), ['ID_REC' => 'ID_QUESTION']);
}

public function getIDTOPIC()
{
    return $this->hasOne(SQuizTopic::className(), ['ID_REC' => 'ID_TOPIC']);
}
```

**Фото как это выглядит:**[image: таблицы]

Comment: вам надо javascript'ом, выгребать все id вопросов, заносить их в другую таблицу и обновлять страницу, или именно этот блок посредством pjax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот переделаный view, в котором реализовано перемещение данных между этими таблицами:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active panel panel-primary" id="questionintopik">
   <div class="row">
      <!-- Таблица №1 -->
      <div class="col-lg-5">
      <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
         <h4>Вопросы не входящие в эту тему</h4>
         <input id="search-avaliable">
         <a href="#" id="btn-refresh"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> </a> <br>
         <?= Html::activeListBox($model, 'ID_REC', $LeftItems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%', 'id' => 'first']) ?>
      <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
   </div>
      <!-- Кнопки -->
      <div class="col-lg-1"> <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

      <a id="btn-add" class="btn btn-success">&gt;&gt;</a><br>
      <a id="btn-remove" class="btn btn-danger">&lt;&lt;</a>
      <!-- Скрипты для кнопок -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(function() {
            $(document).on('click', '#btn-add', function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               var selected = $(document).find('#first option:selected');
               if (selected.length > 0) {
                  selected.appendTo('#second');
               }
            });

            $(document).on('click', '#btn-remove', function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               var selected = $(document).find('#second option:selected');
               if (selected.length > 0) {
                  selected.appendTo('#first');
               }
            });
         });
      </script>

   </div>
      <!-- Таблица №2 -->
      <div class="col-lg-5">
      <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
         <h4>Вопросы входящие в эту тему</h4>
         <input id="search-assigned"><br>
         <?= Html::activeListBox($model, 'ID_REC', $RightItems, ['multiple' => true, 'size' => 20, 'style' => 'width: 100%', 'id' => 'second']) ?>
      <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```